# Android VideoView won't play video from beginning, but plays after seek?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

General: I'm targeting Android 4.1 (API 16) and up. I'm primarily testing on an Android emulator via Android Studio as I don't have access to an older physical device. I'm trying to play a .webm video from external storage. The video codec is VP8, audio codec is Vorbis.

Problem: I'm injecting a VideoView into a LinearLayout (`videoHolderLayout`) as follows:

```
VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(videoView.getContext());
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoHolderLayout.addView(videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
```

If I try to play the video from the beginning, I get the following errors:

```
W/AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died!
W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
D/VideoView: Error: 100,0
```

If I use the MediaController to seek (or `videoView.seekTo(...)`) a few seconds into the video, it plays fine. Using MediaController, if I rewind to the beginning of the video, I'll get the error / crash again.

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is just an issue with the emulator (and possibly Android emulators generally).

Answer (score 0):

write the following code in your onPrepared method

```
    int position = 0;
    videoView.seekTo(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                videoView.start();
            } else {
                videoView.pause();
            }
```